# how to unfocus texfield and hide keybaord on paste flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, focus, textfield

I have a textfield on which i mostly paste content so i want to unfocus textfield and hide keybaord on paste so i have achive to handle on paste using textfield selectionControls but the problem is focusing and keybaord which is reopening i have tired all focus methods to unfocus here is my code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Center(
            child: TextField(
              selectionControls: MySelectionControls(
                onPaste: () {
                  print('onPaste');

                  // FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();

                  // Focus.of(context).unfocus();

                  // FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

                  // FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());

                  // FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                  // if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                  //   currentFocus.focusedChild?.unfocus();
                  // }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySelectionControls extends MaterialTextSelectionControls {
  final Function onPaste;

  MySelectionControls({required this.onPaste});

  @override
  Future<void> handlePaste(TextSelectionDelegate delegate) {
    onPaste();
    return super.handlePaste(delegate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TextSelectionControls? _textSelectionControls;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _textSelectionControls = MySelectionControls(onPaste: onPaste);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  selectionControls: _textSelectionControls,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> onPaste(final TextSelectionDelegate? delegate) async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    });
  }
}

class MySelectionControls extends MaterialTextSelectionControls {
  MySelectionControls({required this.onPaste});
  ValueChanged<TextSelectionDelegate> onPaste;
  @override
  Future<void> handlePaste(TextSelectionDelegate delegate) async {
    onPaste(delegate);
    return super.handlePaste(delegate);
  }
}
```

I have tested this and its working

Comment: it also doesn't work

Comment: Convert to a stateful widget

Comment: same not wokring

Comment: Edited my answer with a working code

Comment: what about flutter web?, will it prevent to paste anything into the textfield by this?

Comment: It doesnt disallow paste but just unfocuses after the paste is done